# PHP count all images on article

Tags: php, arrays

how should I count all images that are displayed in article?

I have array which calls $article and I call article text by `$article['article_text']`. For find first image on array I use

```
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $article['article_text'], $matches);
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
```

but how should I take all images from the article and put them into array for count?

Comment: What's the contents of `$matches`?

Comment: `echo count($matches[1]);` will give you the number of images.

Comment: `count($matches[1])` maybe?

Comment: Are those articles external?

Comment: yes, it is an array from controller

Comment: In that case (if you don't control the HTML) please stop parsing HTML with regex. Your pattern will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your expression is correct, you can simply use `$num_images = count($matches[1]);`

Comment: btw, how should i call all videos using this:

preg_match('/<iframe.*src=\"(.*)\".*><\/iframe>/isU', $array['article_text'], $matches);
           return "(".count($matches[1])." video)";
becouse now it returns only 1 even there is 4 videos

Comment: Might be because you're using preg_match in your example, not preg_match_all.